# How to tell which of the colliders has been collided?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game in which there are enemies, I want to have headshots in the game so I have 2 colliders: one to the head and one to the body. I can't find any good way to tell which is which in the code.

I thought of a solution but I don't like it- a different type of collider to the head, and different type to the body (like polygon and box colliders). It works but I don't think it's good enough (if I want to add more colliders or have two of the same type that wouldn't work).

```
virtual protected void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider2D)
    {
        if (collider2D.gameObject.tag.Equals("Zombie"))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);//destroy bullet
            Zombie zombie = collider2D.gameObject.GetComponent<Zombie>();
            if (collider2D is BoxCollider2D)
                zombie.HeadShot(demage);//headshot
            else zombie.BulletHit(demage);//normal hit
        }
    }
```

I want a way to tag the colliders somehow so I can tell between them.

Comment: Maybe you just could make child objects for each collider?

Comment: thanks I guess i could but a way to tag the colliders in a good way is mush more simple, I hope it's possible.

Comment: I guess you could inherit from BoxCollider or any other collider and add enum as a tag. But i dont think its easier way.

Comment: Let us know how it went :)

Comment: Thanks it works! I created a HeadCollider class that has a collider2d, the enemy has an HeadCollider and it checks if the collider is the same as the head collider the enemy has. I actually realy like this solution.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create public variables of type BoxCollider2D and assign your colliders. When a collision occurs call an IF statement inside of *OnTriggerEnter* to see which one has collided. This will work no matter if there are more of the same types of collider.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BoxCollider2D box01;
    public BoxCollider2D box02;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.IsTouching(box01))
        {
            Debug.Log("1");
        }
        else if(collision.IsTouching(box02))
        {
            Debug.Log("2");
        }
    }
}
```

[isTouching](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.IsTouching.html) is a Unity method which returns a bool depending on a collider that is comparing.

Comment: Yup this is how i would do it haha, super simpel, but the McCorner solution might be better

Comment: This is a simple solution to this question, but if anyone wants to muddle, be my guest.. btw if you like the answer, vote up. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to not add all colliders on the same `GameObject` but rather give each collider it's own child `GameObject` (this way you also can see easily which colliders belongs to which outline in the scene view ;) )

Then you could use a class with an enum to define which type of collider you have there:

```
public class BodyPart : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BodyPartType Type;
}

public enum BodyPartType
{
    Head,
    LeftArm,
    RightArm,
    Body,
    LeftLeg,
    RightLeg
}
```

and attach it to all body parts next to each collider.

Then you could do something like

```
virtual protected void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider2D)
{
    if (collider2D.gameObject.tag.Equals("Zombie"))
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);//destroy bullet

        // Note you then should use GetComponentInParent here
        // since your colliders are now on child objects
        Zombie zombie = collider2D.gameObject.GetComponentInParent<Zombie>();

        var bodyPart = collider2D.GetComponent<BodyPart>();
        switch(bodyPart.Type)
        {
            case BodyPartType.Head:
                zombie.HeadShot(demage);//headshot
                break;

            // you now could differ between more types here

            default:
                zombie.BulletHit(demage);//normal hit
                break;
        }
    }
}
```