# Detect object's collider from OnTriggerEnter?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Let's say **object A** collides with **B**. **Object A** gets an **OnTriggerEnter** triggered. I know that through **Collider other** I can get any info about the **B object's *Collider*** in this case.

But how do I get info about the **A object's *Collider*** from the **OnTriggerEnter** function triggered on this same **A object**?

**EDIT:**

The **object A** has **multiple colliders** and I don't know which of them triggered **OnTriggerEnter**. This is the reason I need to find out which of them triggered the event **from inside of** **OnTriggerEnter**.

Comment: You would just use `GetComponent<Collider>();` with whatever the appropriate `Collider` type is

Comment: I was not precise enough with my question. Sry. I edited it.

Comment: The first solution which I can think of is that every collider must be in a separate GameObject which is a child of the main one. And you attach a script to every collider to see which OnTriggerEnter is called.

Comment: You can check my answer to a similar question like yours [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55563727/how-to-tell-which-of-the-colliders-has-been-collided/55564029#55564029). I believe it has answers to your needs.

Comment: Tried. **Collider** does not have **IsTouching** function. Only **Collider2D** does :(

Comment: If you have multiple colliders on the same object you cannot distinguish between them when a collision happens.

Comment: @PetroKoval My fault, I was thinking you work on 2D. Didn't notice that you removed 2D from a method call.